# A Pirate's Life For Me!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, story, acrostic

### **A Quick Note**

---

If you've seen any of my recent Riley riddles, then you knew this was coming. I've been working on this one for a week, and it was honestly quite tough to figure out what I really wanted the goal to be. Instead of breaking this one down into parts, you'll simply read the story and all of its content, then answer some questions. This one is a bit long winded though so I hope you all enjoy it, and as always, good luck to everyone!

### **The Story**

---

A few months ago I signed up for a cruise through the Caribbean. I have been excited ever since, and as the day got closer the more excited I became. Now, I packed my usual vacation items; fresh clothes, tooth and hair brushes, Q-tips, flip flops, and of course I have to bring my coffee.

The day had finally arrived and I woke up, performed my usual morning routine. I drank coffee, read the newspaper, did a rather brutal leg work out, took a shower, and then got ready to go. I was so excited that I ended up getting pulled over on the way to the docks due to speeding. My opinion, totally worth it. I wanted to get there as fast as possible, I even jokingly asked the officer for an escort.

I made it! I arrived at the docks safe and sound, presented my boarding pass, and was shown to my quarters. It was a fantastic room for being on a cruise ship, I wonder if this is how those on the Titanic felt as they boarded?

[image: Cruise Ship]

About an hour went by and the captain came over the PA system; *ladies and gentlemen, we are about to embark on our journey through the Caribbean. Please ensure that you have all of your belongings accounted for as we will be gone for two weeks.*

### **WOO-HOO!**

Our first destination was for obvious reasons, the Florida Keys. Now, I've already been here before, being a Florida native and all; but I still enjoy paying home a little visit from time to time. After about eight hours we departed and began heading towards Bermuda. Now we're talking! This is the whole reason I wanted to come on this cruise in the first place! The whole mystery behind the triangle is what I wanted to learn about.

The captain came over the PA; *ladies and gentlemen, feel free to get some rest, or enjoy the live entertainment on the upper deck this evening. We should arrive in Bermuda around 0600 hours.*

I decided it was time for me to get some sleep; I wasn't really too interested in playing shuffleboard, or hitting the pool. I have a pool at home, plus I'm surrounded by the ocean. If I really wanted to swim, all I had to do was jump overboard.

### **THUD! CRACK! BOOM!**

All of a sudden I burst from my slumber, what the hell was that noise? It sounded like an explosion! I quickly ran to the top deck to help those in need and what I saw was absolutely unbelievable! It was like being in a movie; I mean, we all remember The Goonies right? Maybe the more recent Pirates of the Caribbean movies?

[image: Pirate Ship]

Well, walking to the top deck was probably a bad idea. I ran back below deck to conceal myself. The next thing I know, a piece of the wall is blitzing past my head! I finally managed to get back to my room and I grabbed my tooth brush, a bar of soap, and a steak knife from dinner the night before. I then ran back out into the corridor of the lower deck attempting to find a place to hide that wouldn't be completely obvious. All of a sudden I felt a sharp pain in the back of my head and everything went black.

I was startled awake by someone dumping a bucket of water on me; as I looked around, I noticed that the room was pretty empty, my clothes were torn, and my shoes were nailed to a post with a piece of paper. I rose to my feet, and walked to the paper where I found the following written on it:

> To your left is a dress, you must look your best; the captain would like to see you.
>
> Beware of your mouth, it can get you thrown out; would you rather be trapped in this room?

I attempted to remove my shoes from the post but I was unable to do so; however, within my shoes I located my phone and a single golden doubloon.

[image: Gold Doubloon]

Of course, I didn't have service, so I could call for help, nor could I figure out where I was. I continued to examine the room, I found a black and blue dress (Victorian era I believe), to my right; the wall behind me had letters carved into it, possibly from the previous prisoners.

[image: Wall]

Was it a warning of some kind? I wasn't sure, but I memorized everything just in case. Since my current clothes were torn, I agreed to my captor's demands and changed into the dress to meet with the captain. I then sat and waited, staring at that doubloon I found; it was quite spectacular and thus brought some light into this dark situation.

A few hours passed by and the door swung open, the silhouette of a man entered the doorway. *I'm pleased that you've agreed to meet the captain madam. Please, follow me.*

I rose to my feet and followed the unnamed man through the bowels of this massive ship. There were ropes hanging everywhere, barrels lining each wall, and plenty of pirates of course. As we climbed the ladder to the deck the sun was blinding. Had I really been down there that long?

The man escorted me to the captains quarters and told me to wait, the captain would be with me shortly. After about half an hour, the captain came walking in with a smile on his face. *Ahhh, you must be the newest member of my crew.*

I was confused at this statement, but to ensure my safety, I went along with it. *Yes, I am sir; how can I serve this mighty ship and her captain?*

*Well, you can begin by proving yourself; answer this riddle, and earn your right to stay aboard my vessel.*

> Rotated right, the suffix is there; tell me, oh tell me, what is four there?
>
> Oscillate for the infix, three degrees left; the answer is hidden, two from the rest.
>
> Ponder the prefix, it is in memory; two letters left, the answer has to be.
>
> Each of these letters, alone of no use; when answered wrong, will leave you confused.

I thought for a moment, and then I realized the answer; as I went to speak, the captain handed me a piece of paper. *Write your answer down on this parchment, and head back to your quarters and await my decision.* I wrote the answer down, and then went back to where I awoke. As I entered the room, I found a new piece of paper on the floor; it was quite old, and the writing was quite odd. I couldn't really figure out what it meant.

> OAs2t9Plsd0nMrFxh0N+QLsxgwtP1XZCxxtVrzxYIqU=

I continued to examine the doubloon, the scratches on the wall, and the paper and I couldn't figure it out. The door swung open, and then I blacked out again (probably from dehydration or lack of food). I'm not really sure what happened next.

---

### Hints

**Hint for the Key**: The riley actually gives the key away and it is not an actual word. It is a combination of letters in all caps.

> Look to the coin, no wait the wall; wait, I think it's both, combined after all.

### **The Questions**

---

- What is the answer to the captain's riddle?
- How was I able to answer the riddle?
- What is the hidden message that the previous prisoner left behind?

Comment: Acoustic: Rope. They called you both sir and madam, what's up with that?

Comment: I knew it. I looked at "**A Quick Now**" and *knew* this was your story :D

Comment: @YoutRied I referred to the captain as sir.

Comment: @user477343 Lol I warned it was coming!

Comment: Could we get another hint?

Comment: If I try this I will run out of brainpower for the day. Take my upvote and good luck everyone!

Comment: in need of some guidance... totally lost in the pool of info in awe... well done @PerpetualJ +1

Comment: is rot13(qernzfgvzr) just a watermark on the wall image or is it something to do with the puzzle?

Comment: Just a watermark, your focus on that image is the scratching.

Answer (score 6):

I have one possible answer albeit only partial. This is my first answer in this community so I don't know whether it is acceptable to answer partially or not.

1) What is the answer to the captain's riddle

> GOLDMINE

2) How was I able to answer the riddle?

> Inference 1: In the image with letters carved in wall, one such carving looks like is MIN4D.

Now, first line from Captain's riddle: Rotated right, the suffix is there; tell me, oh tell me, what is four there?

> Inference 2: Rotating MIN4D right gives DMIN4. Inferring from second part of above line, the suffix is DMINE.

Now, second line from Captain's riddle: Oscillate for the infix, three degrees left; the answer is hidden, two from the rest.

> Inference 3: On the left of the above word MIN4D in the image with letters carved in wall, word DOLF can be seen. As stated by Captain: "the answer is hidden, two from the rest". Inferring 2 of the letter in DOLF is part of infix.

Now, third line from Captain's riddle: Ponder the prefix, it is in memory; two letters left, the answer has to be.

> Inference 4: As memory serves, we conjure the image of single **gold**en doubloon. Combining it with inference 3 (i.e. with the word dOLf), we have the prefix gOLd.

---

> Combining prefix and infix and suffix, we get GOLDMINE

This is what I have yet arrived. Maybe it is correct or maybe I am shooting in the blank.

3) What is the hidden message that the previous prisoner left behind?

Unable to solve: C

Comment: Wow, great first answer, reasoning, and explanation! Welcome to puzzling!! :D

Comment: Perhaps add in photos though and circle where the words are so people know where you found them?